# "Tile error: Error in map(ID=LC08_004063_20130729): List.get: List is empty (index is 0)" Merging Landsat data and BRDF correction in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, libgee

I trying to merge Landsat series data and then applying BRDF correction in GEE.

No error shows when didn't applying BRDF function. But, when I applying BRDF function then following Error appears

Error in map(ID=LC08_006063_20130828):
List.get: List is empty (index is 0).

My working code is
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Frajitgupta1993%2FAGB_India%3AUntitledFile3

Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.